# how to replace the parameters of an anchor link with jquery?

Tags: jquery, url, href

I am learning jquery now. I want to replace the parameters of a url with another on page load. For example here is my code

```
 <div class="changeparam">
<a href="http://demo.org/post.php?i=123&p=456&s=789">Link</a>
 </div>
```

Now I need to change the value of the params i,p and s to different values say abc,def,ghi respectively. How can i do it on page load?

Comment: While this is possible, it's not ideal. Where is the Url being generated? Could you not change it at that level?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: it can be changed at the URL generation level. But the problem is that we have to cache the page contents. So next time another user loads the content, the cache is loaded. So this can cause passing wrong information about the user and the contents.

Comment: In that case you should look at fixing your caching system.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Do you have any suggestions on it? How can I replace the parametes from the cache file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to know the old values? If not can't you do something along the lines of the following (this assumes the simple case that all links will have the same query string and would need to be extended if this is not the case):

```
$(document).ready( function ( ) {
    // Get the full address from the original link
    var old_fulladdr = $('div.changeparam a').attr('href');

    // split it to get the actual file address
    var old_addr_parts = old_fulladdr.split('?');

    // This may need something more complex...
    var new_querystring = 'i=abc&p=def&g=ghi';

    // This changes the href of the link to the new one.
    $('div.changeparam a').attr('href',old_addr_parts[0] + '?' + new_querystring);

});​
```

UPDATE:
 I've created a more flexible function that takes a querystring, an array of items to be replaced and an array of replacement values then outputs a new query string. Have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LWzZR/1

Also, I agree with the commenters on your question - whilst it's possible, it's not recommended :)

Comment: I dont need the old params. I just want to refresh the params when the page is loaded. What if I just want to refresh only one param?

Comment: Give me 5 minutes, I'll have a fiddle.

Comment: thanks. Please consider of the option so that if needed i can keep the value of "i" same and change "p" and "s" only.

Comment: Please see the jsfiddle I've just linked in my answer.

Comment: thank you verymuch. That fiddle worked. Now the problem is that I am having multiple such divs in my site all with the same class name. Now when I run the jquery script, its replacing the all the links to the first link. How can i run it for individual links?

Comment: ianhales : Why you all are not recommending it?

Comment: How would you differentiate between links? If you can do that, just apply the function to each one individually (possibly use `$('div.changeparam a').each()`.

it's not recommended because it's much better to do this stuff server side. What if your user has javascript turned off?

Comment: thanks for the comment. I got it working now.
My site already uses many jquery lib functions. So if the user turns of js, he wont be able to use other functionalities too. SO they have to enable js.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/docs/files/jquery-ba-bbq-js.html#jQuery.param.querystring%28build_url%29) plugin.  It makes dealing with querystrings much less of an issue.

I think you'd want to try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.param.querystring($(".changeparam").attr("href"), {i:123, p:456, s:789})
});
```

It's got a lot of cool stuff for manipulating querystrings and you don't have to reinvent the wheel here.